# Passing `Num` as `Int` for `take`

Tags: haskell

Reading through [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness), I was working on the following:

```
import System.Random

-- We could make a function that generates a finite stream of numbers and a new generator.
finiteRandoms :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => Int -> g -> ([a], g) 
finiteRandoms 0 g = ([], g) 
finiteRandoms n g = let (num, gen) = random g 
                    in (take n $ num : randoms gen, gen)
```

Note that the above function is incorrect as it returns the "next" `gen` rather than the `n`th one.

Per LYAH, the correct signature is:

`finiteRandoms :: (RandomGen g, Random a, Num n) => n -> g -> ([a], g)`.

When I tried `take n $ num` where `n` was a `Num` type, it failed to compile:

`Could not deduce (n ~ Int)`.

Given a `Num`, how can I convert it to an `Int` to call `take n`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't `take` require an `Int` argument? Where did you find that `Num n` was the way to go in LYAH?

Comment: using `take n` is not the way to go in LYAH for this problem. I developed an alternate solution (which is wrong). During development of the wrong solution, I encountered the above question - how to convert a `Num` to `Int` in order to call `take ...`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith There isn't a way to convert a `Num a => a` to an `Int` in general.  Why?  Well how would you convert the complex number `1 + 2i` to an `Int`?  What if it's a quaternion?  There are plenty of numeric types that do not have a canonical conversion to `Int`.  In fact, [the Reals can not be encoded as `Int`s directly](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountablyInfinite.html).  If you want to convert from a `Double` to an `Int`, you'll need to use a lossy conversion, such as `round`.

Comment: thanks @bheklilr. Care to answer for credit please?

Comment: pls mark it as answer too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a way to convert a `Num a => a` to an `Int` in general.  This is because there isn't a canonical mapping from many numeric types to integers.  For example, it's impossible to map complex numbers to integers in a 1-to-1 correspondence.  If you want to convert, for example, `Double` to `Int`, you can use `round`, but there isn't a function that can do this for any numeric type.

Comment: There are also lots of integers that can't be represented by `Int`s. For example, `toInteger(maxBound::Int) + 1` can't be converted to an `Int`. It would also be *very* surprising if `encodeFloat (toInteger (floatRadix (undefined::Double)) ^ toInteger (floatDigits (undefined::Double)) - 1) (snd (floatRange (undefined::Double))-floatDigits (undefined::Double))` were representable as an `Int`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use a polymorphic type for `n`, there's always [`genericTake`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericTake) from `Data.List`:

```
genericTake :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

For the reasons bhkelir points out, you won't get as general as `Num` though.